# jQuery selector pass all instances and not just the one which originated the event

Tags: jquery

I have a form and i want to check when the user stop typing, that's done, now i used this:

```
detectTyping($("input"));
```

To attach it to every input element on the page, it works, but the problem comes when i stop typing, it affects all the inputs elements on the page and no just the one which just have triggered it. Is there a way to init the function to all the input elements at same time and affect only the element which triggered the finishTyiping function. I'd rather do it like that, than init every input with an id.

There's a live demo: [jsfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/y39hj2ng/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that inside a jQuery event handler, `this` is the element that is the source of the event. So you want `$(this)`, but there's an additional wrinkle, which is that if you try to put that inside the timeout function, `this` will mean something different in that scope. So you have to put the event source in a variable first, like this:

```
        var eventSrc = $(this);
        typingTimer = setTimeout(function(){
            doneTyping(eventSrc);
        }, doneTypingInterval);
```

You probably also want `if($(this).val)` instead of `if($(sender).val)`. `sender` there is `$('input')`, i.e. the collection of all input elements.

The longer answer is that this probably still isn't going to do what you want. After making those modifications, try tabbing into a different field and waiting. The problem is that on every keyup handler, you're cancelling the last one with the clearTimeout call, so the one that executes is the one when the Tab key is pressed.

Comment: Thanks, it worked, and it did exactly what i wanted, what was do a boucing, and know when for example the user stop typing for a interval of time to make a validation and toggle classes.